# Replace Into without checking Auto Increment Primary Key?

Tags: mysql

I have the following table (`tbl_test`) in MySQL server:

```
id    AUTO_INCRECMENT  PRIMARY
text1 VARCHAR(20)
```

and inserted a row of data:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_test (text1) VALUES ('Apple')

id    text1
===========
1     Apple
```

Then, I plan to use `REPLACE INTO` to check for existing value and insert if needed:

```
REPLACE INTO tbl_test (text1) VALUES ('Apple')
```

But it inserted a new row.

```
id    text1
===========
1     Apple
2     Apple
```

How can I check for existing data and insert only if needed (ignoring auto increment primary key)?

Comment: Can you use unique index on column?

Comment: I can use it on the columns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make use of UPSERT

```
INSERT INTO tbl_test
(`text1`)
VALUES( 'Apple')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
`text1` = VALUES(text1);
```

Comment: this works great. the auto increment id does not get updated either.

Comment: Note that this does no longer work with `InnoDB`. If you want this to work you have to use `MyISAM` (which comes at a slight performance penalty that gets worse the more concurrent access there are).

Answer (score 2):

As of official documentation [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html)

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index

You have to specify already use primary key in your statement of for your text field add a unique index to see it in action

For existing primary key eg 1 use

```
REPLACE INTO `table1` (id,text1) VALUES (1,'Apple1');
```

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e86b3/1)

Another example for unique key

```
ALTER TABLE `table1` ADD UNIQUE INDEX `indexu` (`text1`);
```

Sample data

```
INSERT INTO `table1` (id,text1) VALUES (1,'Apple');
INSERT INTO `table1` (id,text1) VALUES (2,'Banana');
```

Lets update id for value `Banana`

```
REPLACE INTO `table1` (id,text1) VALUES (5,'Banana');
```

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2ff3b/1)

Comment: works like charm, but is there any chance that the Auto ID won't get updated? Currently the ID will change once `REPLACE INTO` is executed. Or I should use 2 queries (1 for checking existence, 1 for inserting?)

Comment: @Raptor my second example is for unique index and for explanation i have updated id column but it doesn't mean it will update primary key you can specify other columns in query and when there is any value repeated then it will update that row instead of creating new one